# Application windows freezes when I click the button (C#)

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, freeze

I'm developing a Windows application that:

- Connects to FTP and send/receive files
- Connects to a server via SSH and send commands
- Creating Excel report
- and some other stuff

All of these tasks start when the user click a button. The problem is that after clicking the button:

- Cursor turn into a hand icon
- window freezes and user can't do anything (even moving it)
- Even the "Please Wait" animation doesn't play and process log is barely shown

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do your work on a background thread.  The easiest way to get started with background threads is the [background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

When you do work on background threads you need to invoke onto the main thread if you want to update GUI components.  The background worker has a [Report Progress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx) method which will allow you to do this.

Read up on the basics of threading and give it a shot. If you run into issues, come back and post a new question with specific code examples.